# Simplify if statement with multiple or's involving same variable?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have an if statement like this:

```
if (a > x || b > x || c > x || d > x) {}
```

Assume it always involves the same repeated variable (x in this case) and the same operation, but the operation isn't the same between all uses.  For example, another if statement may use:

```
if (x.Contains(a) || x.Contains(b) || x.Contains(c) || x.Contains(d)) {}
```

Is there a way to simplify these if statements in C# so we don't end up typing the same thing over and over?  I'd prefer not making an extra function to call for this instance.

Comment: no there is noway out...this is how logic works....

Comment: I was thinking there might be some Enumerable interface that would take an operation to do the compare on all elements or something like that.

Comment: Oh, and by "not using a function call" - I don't mean your solution can't use lambdas or something that calls a function in the background technically - I just don't want to write a separate function for this purpose in my code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use LINQ but it don't think it's very useful if you have only four conditions:

```
if (new[] {a,b,c,d}.Any(current => current > x))
```

and

```
if (new[] {a,b,c,d}.Any(current => x.Contains(current)))
```

Comment: Agreed. There is definitely some loss, in terms of readability, using LINQ. So, when having to evaluate a small number of conditions, I believe the `if..or..` syntax is the more appropriate choice. At the point that your logic becomes too cumbersome to read, try the LINQ implementation.

Comment: Sounds sensible to me; we actually did have a lot more than 4 but I still agree that it might not be the best way to go :) Thank you for the solution/input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq's [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) method to `||` multiple conditions together.

```
var tests = new int[] { a, b, c, d };

if (tests.Any(y => y > x)) { }

if (tests.Any(y => x.Contains(y))) { }
```

And by the way, if you need to have multiple conditions `&&`-ed together you can use [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx).

```
if (tests.All(y => y > x)) { }

if (tests.All(y => x.Contains(y))) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing stopping you making your own extensions to make things a little clearer;

```
public static class LinqExtension
{
    public static bool ContainsAny<TInput>(this IEnumerable<TInput> @this, IList<TInput> items)
    {
        return @this.Any(items.Contains);
    }
}
```